# Unable to find oozie-site.xml in CDH5.01 version

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I use cloudera hadoop CDH5.01
During oozie execution I'm getting error
     `Jobtracker [cloudera:5032] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelist`

In order to fix this issue, I require to add resource manager address to the whitelist in oozie-site.xml.
Cloudera documents say its located in /etc/oozie/conf/. Modifying the file is not reflected in ooize console. configuration which oozie is using is from somewhere else which is getting generated whenever I start oozie.
eg
 `/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/294-oozie-OOZIE_SERVER/oozie-site.xml`

How to find the actual configuration file which is being used which cloudera hadoop + oozie

Answer (score 0):

You have the file oozie-default.xml in $OOZIE_HOME/conf

Answer (score 0):

The folder you listed is where the actual oozie-site.xml is written to; for example `/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/294-oozie-OOZIE_SERVER/oozie-site.xml`. Whenever oozie is started a process directory is created and its configuration is written somewhere under that directory.

If you need to modify values that get written to oozie-site.xml then you must modify those values in Cloudera Manager. Modifying the oozie-site.xml directly will not work as the configuration will just be overwritten the next time the service is started. Open cloudera manager in a browser, Select your cluster, Select the oozie service, select the configuration tab. Then modify the setting in question. You will see an icon next to the service after you save the changes that dictates the configuration needs to be redeployed and that the service needs to be restarted to pick up those new changes.